# org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException... Message payload is of type: NullPayload

Tags: soap, mule, mule-studio

The inbound of the Web Service Soap Consumer states that the inbound of the component, even though I set the payload.

Here is an image of my flow (in action):

[image]

Here is the code behind the worfklow:

```
<flow name="getScope" doc:name="getScope">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <message-filter doc:name="Filter favicon">
        <not-filter>
            <wildcard-filter pattern="/favicon.ico" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </not-filter>
    </message-filter>
    <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:ser=&quot;http://xxxxx.xxxx.xxx/services/&quot;&gt;&lt;soapenv:Header/&gt;&lt;soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;ser:GetDetails&gt;&lt;!--Optional:--&gt;&lt;ser:request&gt;&lt;ser:Code&gt;xxxxxx&lt;/ser:Code&gt;&lt;/ser:request&gt;&lt;/ser:GetDetails&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Envelope&gt;"/>
    <message-properties-transformer name="contentTypeTextXML">
        <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="WebService_xxxxxxxxxxxServiceBasicHttpEndpoint" operation="GetDetails" doc:name="Web Service Consumer Organisation"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Here is the log:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2014-05-27 23:43:54,004 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.component.simple.LogComponent: 
********************************************************************************
* Message received in service: getScope. Content is: '/'                       *
********************************************************************************
INFO  2014-05-27 23:43:54,015 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.component.simple.LogComponent: 
********************************************************************************
* Message received in service: getScope. Content is: '<soapenv:Envelope        *
* xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"                    *
* xmlns:ser="http://traini...[100 of 291]'                                     *
********************************************************************************
INFO  2014-05-27 23:43:54,267 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2014-05-27 23:43:54,275 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2014-05-27 23:43:54,275 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2014-05-27 23:43:54,276 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.https.mule.default.dispatcher.1981074383'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-05-27 23:43:54,288 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.https.mule.default.dispatcher.1981074383'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-05-27 23:43:58,409 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.http.HttpsClientMessageDispatcher: Received a redirect, but followRedirects=false. Response code: 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR 2014-05-27 23:43:58,480 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : An unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request. All details have been logged.. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. An unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request. All details have been logged.. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException)
  org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1:164 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/ws/consumer/SoapFaultException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException: An unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request. All details have been logged.. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.process(WSConsumer.java:164)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: add the exception log here.

Comment: @user1760178 added the log here.